# my project does not see the a specific import despite its presence in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking at this [link](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/pages/maven.html) and I added as they suggested:

Dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
        <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.4</version>
        <type>content-package</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
        <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the sub-package:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.24</version>
    <configuration>
        <targetURL>mytargeturl</targetURL>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
        <properties>
           <acHandling>merge</acHandling>
        </properties>

        <subPackages>
            <subPackage>
               <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
               <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
               <filter>true</filter>
            </subPackage>
        </subPackages>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, in my java class when I try to import like this:

```
import com.adobe.acs.*/
```

I'm getting this error:

> `acs` is not resolved

I tried running:

```
mvn clean package -U
```

But it doesn't compile, it throws the above-mentioned error.
What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you put your dependency just in the `<dependenyManagement>` block. this is only for centralizing dependency information like version or scope. so you will need to put references for your desired dependencies as well in your pom.

you'll need a block like this

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
      <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
      <type>content-package</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
      <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-bundle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

see here:
[Maven - introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)